# how do I read array within csv and store that array within mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, csv

[This is my data.csv, there is cast column and its rows have array within it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGk8M.png)

I want to retrieve that arrays from csv into mongodb.
I want to work with array within data.csv, but when i tried to import my csv into mongodb Compass, there is no datatype filter for array. Moreover, I tried to write a code to read data from nodejs but using TYPEOF operator on data gave me output String.

I want to preserve my datatype of array.

Comment: You can try the [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/) tool

Answer (score -1):

First you need to convert your csv file into an array of Objects and then upload that into mongo.
You can use insertMany from mongoose to make this thing work

```
[Collection-Name].insertMany(ArrayOfObj, { ordered: false, rawResult: true }, async 
function (err, result) {
 if(err) throw err;
 // do your thing
})
```